# Linq NOT EXISTS multiple tables

Tags: linq

I want to do a LINQ NOT EXISTS on query MULTIPLE TABLES.

All examples on Google or SO are handling **two tables** I'm working with three so I'm struggling as a newbie on LINQ on how to reference them correctly.

First I tried this LINQ query

```
  var nocertificates = (
  from x in rmdb.t_certificates
  from ce in rmdb.t_user_certificates
  from u in rmdb.t_users
  where u.id == ce.uid && ce.value != x.id
  select x).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ViewModelCheckBox()
      {
         Value = x.id.ToString(),
         Name = x.name,
         Checked = false
      });
```

I used the ugly three times from as I'm not that good with creating types for joining.
But that gave wrong result and I realized I had to go for a **NOT EXISTS**

So I built a new query in T-SQL

This is the SQL query it works!

```
select distinct * from t_certificates tc
where NOT EXISTS
(
select distinct * from t_users tu, t_user_certificates tuc
WHERE tu.email = 'user@email.com'
and tu.id = tuc.[uid]
and tuc.value = tc.id
)
```

**How would I do that in LINQ?**

***This is the question, I will award my answer for that!***

**BUT!**

When we are at it... I'm really curious on the answer.. Is it possible to do one LINQ query that return an Ienumerable with both those that EXISTS and NOT EXISTS resulting in an object which will hold DIFFERENT VALUES on the checked property 
 **EXISTS -> CHECKED = true 
NOT EXISTS -> CHECKED = false**

This is how I create my object.

```
   .Select(x => new ViewModelCheckBox()
      {
         Value = x.id.ToString(),
         Name = x.name,
         Checked = this should be different based on exists or not
      });
```

Comment: For your second question: Conceptuallly this is just a left outer join with a WHERE clause that selects only records with a non-nullable field from the right-hand table being NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQ answer should look something like this (untested):

```
 var nocertificates = 
  from x in rmdb.t_certificates
  join tuc in (
    from u in rmdb.t_users
    join ce in rmdb.t_user_certificates on u.id == ce.uid 
    select ce.value 
  ) on tuc.value = tc.id into tuc
  from y in tuc.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where y == null
  select x;
```

Comment: Hmmm somethings wrong, the tables are not consistent... I used other names for linq and SQL :( I get the scope wrong..

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using!

```
var query = (from tc in rmdb.t_certificates 
             where !(
                     from tu in rmdb.t_users
                     from tuc in rmdb.t_user_certificates
                     where tu.email == username
                     && tu.id == tuc.uid
                     && tuc.value == tc.id select tc).AsEnumerable().Any() 
                     select new ViewModelCheckBox()
                                { Checked = false,
                                  intconverter = tc.id,
                                  Name = tc.name
                                });
```